# TCPDF Performance Issue

Tags: performance, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF library for creating reports. It gives me quick result when I fetch few rows of data from database. But when database returns hundred of rows, it takes minutes. I searched forums also. Many people mentioned to disable fonts.

```php
    protected $font_subsetting = false;
```

But still failed to get good performance. My report code is:

```php
$html.='<tr  >
        <td align="left" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #999;"><strong>'.$i.'</strong></td>
<td align="left" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #999;">'.$belt_no.'</td>
<td align="left" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #999;">'.$hname.'</td>
        <td align="left" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #999;">'.$hdob.'</td>
        <td align="left" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #999;">'.$hhiredate.'</td>
        <td align="left" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #999;">'.$hhomeps.'</td>
                    <td align="left" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #999;">'.$hrank.'</td>
        <td align="left" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #999;">'.$st_date.'</td>
        <td align="left" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #999;">'.$police_station.'</td>   </tr>'; $i++; }    $html.='</table>';$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Comment: Please not that, i am fetching data from a single table . i have not any complex query. the only problem is the generation of pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have hundreds of rows it's most likely going to take time , i don't know what you are doing in your loop but i see in your code that you are using variables such $belt_no , you can optimise you code by avoiding variable as much as possible. if you are fetching from a table
istead of doing :

```
while($ligne = mysql_fect_array($res)){
$belt_no = $ligne['belt_no'];
$hdob= $ligne['hdob'];
$html = '<td align="left" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #999;">'.$belt_no.'</td>
<td align="left" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #999;">'.$hname.'</td>
';
}
```

you can skipp the variables and save some memory space:

```
while($ligne = mysql_fect_array($res)){

$html = '<td align="left" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #999;">'.$ligne['belt_no'].'</td>
<td align="left" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #999;">'.$ligne['hdob'].'</td>
';
}
```